React three fiber - setting up postprocessing using effectComposer and Passes (OutlinePass) from three.js addons
I'm having a hard time using the R3F -postprocessing library so I decided to use raw threejs classes:
By diving into the R3F extending third party library tutorials I managed to setup the renderPass and the outlinePass with typescript
https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/typescript
import { EffectComposer } from "three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer";
import { RenderPass } from "three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass";
import { OutlinePass } from "three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/OutlinePass";
extend({ RenderPass, EffectComposer, OutlinePass });
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      outlinePass: Node<OutlinePass, typeof OutlinePass>;
    }
  }
}

export default function GaussianViewer({
  return (
    /**
     * It creates a scene, a camera & Raycaster.
     * It also sets up the webGlrenderer and the animationLoop.
     */
    <Canvas
      gl={{ localClippingEnabled: true }}
      onClick={onCanvasClickHandler}
    >
      <ViewerContent />
    </Canvas>
  );
})

function ViewerContent(){
  const { camera, gl, scene, raycaster, get, set } =
    useThree();
return (
      <effectComposer args={[gl]}>
        <renderPass
          attach="passes"
          args={[scene, camera]}
        />
        <outlinePass attach="passes" />
        {/* <outlinePass /> */}
      </effectComposer>
)
}

However, after successfully setting up the effect composer and the passes, a new issue came up as shown in picture:

is it a reason to believe that it's better use the R3F -postprocessing library since R3F have some issues implementing the third party raw threejs add-ons? or is there any way I can fix this issue?

I ran into a similar issue where the @react-three/postprocessing library would not work with my existing project, most likely because of build issues with NextJS.
Using this post as inspiration, I created a quick component that makes it easy to create a stack of three-js post-processing effects in react-three-fiber:
import { EffectComposer } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer';
import { RenderPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass';
import { DotScreenPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/DotScreenPass';
import { RenderPixelatedPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPixelatedPass.js';
import { OutlinePass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/OutlinePass';
import { UnrealBloomPass } from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass';
import { Canvas, extend, Object3DNode, useFrame, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { Vector2 } from 'three';
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

extend({
  RenderPass,
  EffectComposer,
  OutlinePass,
  DotScreenPass,
  RenderPixelatedPass,
  UnrealBloomPass,
});

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      outlinePass: Object3DNode<OutlinePass, typeof OutlinePass>;
      dotScreenPass: Object3DNode<DotScreenPass, typeof DotScreenPass>;
      renderPixelatedPass: Object3DNode<RenderPixelatedPass, typeof RenderPixelatedPass>;
      unrealBloomPass: Object3DNode<UnrealBloomPass, typeof UnrealBloomPass>;
    }
  }
}

// Uncomment the passes you want to use
export const ThreeEffects = () => {
  const { camera, gl, scene } = useThree();
  const composer = useRef<EffectComposer>();

  useEffect(() => {
    composer.current = new EffectComposer(gl);
    composer.current.addPass(new RenderPass(scene, camera));

    // const pixelatedPass = new RenderPixelatedPass(6, scene, camera);
    // composer.current.addPass(pixelatedPass);

    const bloomPass = new UnrealBloomPass(
      new Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight),
      1.5,
      0.4,
      0.85
    );
    composer.current.addPass(bloomPass);

    // const dotScreenPass = new DotScreenPass(
    //   new Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight),
    //   0.5,
    //   0.8
    // );
    // composer.current.addPass(dotScreenPass);

    // const outlinePass = new OutlinePass(new Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), scene, camera);
    // composer.current.addPass(outlinePass);

    // Resize the composer when the window size changes
    composer.current.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }, [gl, scene, camera]);

  useFrame(() => {
    composer.current?.render();
  }, 1);

  return null;
};

https://gist.github.com/jelling/f2974011ae1dce107f7aba1406a7795b

My bad, I forgot to pass the outlinePass arguments as per following example:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_postprocessing_outline.html#L249
  args={[
    new THREE.Vector2(
      window.innerWidth,
      window.innerHeight
    ),
    scene,
    camera,
  ]}

